# PDO execute returns 1 but no row affected?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I am getting some weird behavior when using my PDO delete method and I'm hoping to get some answers why. For some reason, when I perform a delete (in this case the table is empty) the query returns 1. According to the documentation, it should be returning 0 if no rows are modified. Here is the code.

```
protected function dsn() {
    return 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db . ';charset=' . $this->charset;
}

//my PDO attribute options//
protected $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        ];
//I have separate connections for different queries with different permissions
depending on what I need to do//
protected function connectDelete() {
    $dsn = $this->dsn();
    $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->userDelete, $this->passDelete, $options);

    return $this->pdo;
}

function deleteQuery($query, $values = []) {

    $prepare = $this->connectDelete()->prepare($query);
    $result = $prepare->execute($values);

    return $result;
}
```

With all of the relevant code out of the way, here is the query.

```
require_once $root.'/classes/userDB.php';
$db = new userDB();

$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE primaryKey = ? AND user_id = ?";
$values = [$pk_id,$user_id];
$result = $db->deleteQuery($query, $values);

echo $result;
returns 1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT #1 :**
So I tried `rowCount()` to see what the outcome would be, and I got the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object...

So seems that the query is failing?

**EDIT #2 :**
Here is the new function that will return the affected rows.

```
function deleteQuery($query, $values = []) {

    $prepare = $this->connectDelete()->prepare($query);
    $prepare->execute($values);
    $result = $prepare->rowCount();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `rowCount`?

Comment: @danronmoon - `$count = $result->rowCount(); echo $count;`

Comment: Off-topic: Wrap your connect statement in a try-catch block. If for some reason your connection fails, everyone will be able to see the password of your application by following the stack trace (assuming production here). Unless you work with HHVM. http://3v4l.org/sUkHM

Comment: @RichardA That's really the job of a global exception handler and/or appropriate error reporting/display settings on your production machine. *Don't* wrap everything in a `try..catch` block just for the sake of avoiding information leakage, that's madness and negating the use of exceptions for error handling.

Comment: @deceze That's very true, but it's still better than having your connection fail and giving the password to everyone (Assuming error reporting is on on the production environment for some reason), proper error handling should be done nontheless. Consider this a minimal example of handing it.

Comment: Again, just set `display_errors` to `false` on your production machine's PHP config. There are a thousand other ways you could leak information unless you do that. This really is a sysadmin level thing, not something you need to screw up every single line of code for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**`PDOStatement::execute`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
>
> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

`true` output as string turns into `1`. This doesn't say anything about how many rows got deleted, just that the query succeeded (i.e. was syntactically correct and executed without errors). If you want to know how many rows were affected, you're looking for [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: I see, I was looking at different documentation. I had a thought this was the case. Can you tell me the difference between `PDO::exec` (what I was referencing) and `PDOStatement::execute`?

Comment: As the documentation says: *"`exec`: Execute an SQL statement and return the number of affected rows"*. It's shorthand for `prepare()`, `execute()`, `rowCount()` when you don't really need a prepared statement, because you've got no parameters for the query.